# Put a var inside other var PHP

Tags: php, variables

this is a simple thing, but I'm struggling with this. I need to put a var inside another. I need to put the author var, inside the var layout. How can I do this? Here is the example.

```
$layout='
<h2 class="title"><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
<p class="meta">Sunday, December 03, 2013 7:27 AM Posted by <a href="#">'.$Someone.'</a></p>
<div class="entry">
</div>';

if($autor=="john")
  $someone=$autor;
  echo $layout;
else if($autor=="mary")
  $someone=$autor;
  echo $layout;
```

Comment: conditional first, then just call the variable $someone inside your variable $layout. ;D

Comment: Yo dawg! I heard you like variables ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to change the order of your code a bit. You must define a variable before you can use it:

```
  $someone=$autor;

$layout='
<h2 class="title"><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
<p class="meta">Sunday, December 03, 2013 7:27 AM Posted by <a href="#">'.$someone.'</a></p>
<div class="entry">
</div>';

echo $layout;
```

The if statement can also be simplified since `$someone` always becomes the value of `$autor`. In fact, you really could eliminate that altogether.

Also, control structures must use curly braces if the blocks they contain are more than one line.

PHP variables are also case sensitive. So `$someone` and `$Someone` do not refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the if/else condition since it does not make any sense:

```
$layout='<h2 class="title"><a href="#">Title</a></h2><p class="meta">Sunday, December 03, 2013 7:27 AM Posted by <a href="#">'.$autor.'</a></p>
<div class="entry">
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to delegate the $someone variable before trying to call it, you also need to keep the same casing throughout for the variable:

```
if($autor=="john"){
  $someone=$autor;
} else if($autor=="john") {
  $someone=$autor;
}

$layout='
<h2 class="title"><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
<p class="meta">Sunday, December 03, 2013 7:27 AM Posted by <a href="#">'.$someone.'</a></p>
<div class="entry">
</div>';

echo $layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not "putting a variable inside another variable". It's delaying evaluation, and/or delaying string interpolation.

It's possible, remotely, but in this case your solution is simple: simply *don't build `$layout` so early!*